# I wrote up some simple scheme functions, but apparently none of them work and I'm wondering why

Tags: function, scheme

I wrote up a few little scheme functions

```html
; Given a list, this should return the maximum value in the list.
(define (maxInt lst)
 (if (empty? lst) 0   ; if the list is empty, return 0
  (max(first lst) (maxInt(rest lst)))))
  ; ^ What this line does is recursively take the maximum of pairs in the list.
  ; Ex. If the list was (7 3 6 2), this line would take the max of 7 and (the max of 3 and(the max of 2 and 6)),
  ; returning a result of 7.  
  
  
; The zip3 function.  Takes three lists of integers and returns a list of ordered triples containing the first, second, or third elements of each original list(i.e. an ordered triple containing the first elements of each list, etc)

(define (zip3 lst1 lst2 lst3)
 (if (or((not(= (length lst1)(length lst2))) (not(= (length lst2)(length lst3))) (not(= (length lst 1)(length lst3))))) (error "Error")
  (append (map car(lst1 lst2 lst3)) (map cadr(lst1 lst2 lst3)) (map caddr(lst1 lst2 lst3)))))
; This says 'if list 1 and 2 are different lengths or list 2 and 3 are different lengths or list 1 and 3 are different lengths, return an error.
; Otherwise, append the list containing the ordered triple of the second element of each list and that containing said triple of the third element
; to the list containing the ordered triple of the first element of each list.'


; The compute function.  takes a list of integers and and integer x and computes a + bx + cx^2 + etc, with a, b, c, etc being the ints in the list.

(define (compute polyLst x)
 (for ([i (length polyLst)])
  (+ (* (list-ref polyLst i) (expt x i)))))
; Recursion was hinted at for this one, but I found it easier to just use a for loop.  This takes the sum of the products of each element of the list and
; x raised to the power of that element's index in the list.
```

I used the scheme notation exactly right(I thought), but none of these functions worked upon testing with a test program that called them.  I'm really confused as to why these functions didn't work.  It doesn't make any sense to me.  I just want to know what I did wrong.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "do not work"? Do they return wrong results or do they throw errors / exceptions?

Comment: `(length lst 1)` should probably be `(length lst1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maxInt` seems to work.

`zip3` has a few parentheses errors, must use `list` and should read

```
(define (zip3 lst1 lst2 lst3)
  (if (or (not(= (length lst1)(length lst2))) (not(= (length lst2)(length lst3))) (not(= (length lst1)(length lst3))))
      (error "Error")
      (append (map car (list lst1 lst2 lst3)) (map cadr (list lst1 lst2 lst3)) (map caddr (list lst1 lst2 lst3)))))
```

and `compute` needs to use `for/sum`:

```
(define (compute polyLst x)
  (for/sum ([i (length polyLst)])
    (* (list-ref polyLst i) (expt x i))))
```

---

Some refactoring ideas:

```
(define (maxInt lst)
  (apply max lst))

(define (zip3 . l) 
  (flatten (apply map list l)))

(define (compute polyLst x)
  (for/sum ([(e n) (in-indexed polyLst)])
    (* e (expt x n))))
```